# Does a statement after return encounters even execute the statement after it

Tags: c

Will `printf("hello")` statement in the function `fact()` will ever get executed? If yes than why it doesn't get printed when call the function fact in `main`? If not then does this `return` statement returns the value to the function and statement `printf("Hello")` is never approached.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1; 
    else
        return (n * fact(n - 1)); 
    printf("Hello");
}

main()
{
    printf("%d", fact(6)); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What makes you think it will, or will never, get executed? In other words, why do you ask this question?

Comment: "does this return statement returns the value to the function": do you mean "returns the value to main"?

Comment: The compiler will likely remove the printf call entirely.

Comment: You get an 'unreachable code' warning at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [*Law of Excluded Middle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) is incredibly useful for formal reasoning about `if` statements. The two choices that you have in your code are as follows:

- `n` is equal to `1`, and
- `n` is *not* equal to `1`.

There is no third "middle" state in this logic.

Now let's go back to your code, and see what happens depending on the value of `n`. When it is `1`, your code returns `1`. When `n` is *not* one, your code returns a result of some calculation.

In order for `printf("Hello")` to be reached, `n` needs to be equal to one and not equal to one at the same time (i.e. `n==1 && n!=1` must be true). The law of excluded middle lets you mathematically prove that this expression is `false` for all values of `n`, meaning that the `printf` line is unreachable under any circumstances. Optimizing C compilers will issue a warning, and remove this "dead code" from the executable that they generate.

Answer (score 0):

```
int fact(int n)
{
if(n==1)
   return 1; //statement 1 
else
   return (n*fact(n-1)); //statement 2
printf("Hello");
}
```

A function ends with a return statement. The return statement specifies that the function is ending while returning the following information.

whenever the function is called with any value of n, the function always ends execution in either statement 1 or statement 2, and thus never reaches the printf statement